# C# - I can't find mxparser dll

Tags: c#, parsing, math, dll

I am creating a software in which i need a really good math parser, i found out that mxparser is a grat one so wanted to try it out, however, i downloaded the whole source, went to the specified folder but i didnt see any dll to add to my project...
https://github.com/mariuszgromada/mXparser
tht is the github link
according to the helloworld tutorial, the dll is supposed to be in
mxparser/current/c sharp/bin/release
but there is nothing there
so my question is that: is there somewhere else i can get the dll or is there any other method that i can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nuget as previously suggested, If you still prefer dll then follow the download link in the release section on github or better on the mathparser.org page

http://mathparser.org/mxparser-downloads/

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathParser.org-mXparser/

https://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22MathParser.org-mXparser%22

https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser/releases

Best regards

Answer (score 2):

I would use NuGet to manage your dependencies. It just makes things easier on you. It also appears there is a package for mXparser.

Comment: I agree - I won't write Java without Maven now.

Comment: i wanted to do that but my nuget package tab doesnt open

Comment: @user8086906 Can you access the Package Manager Console?
Here is where you can find the command to download the particular package: 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/MathParser.org-mXparser/